# error running vagrant up with Laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been successfully using homestead for about an hour now, but when i suspended my virtual machine with `vagrant suspend` and tried to get it up again using `vagrant up` i got this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

What does this mean? The vagrant docs say that

> The shell provisioner takes various options. One of inline or path is
>   required

Do i need to pass in some arguments somewhere? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

this is my vagrantfile:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/aliases")

require_relative 'scripts/homestead.rb'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

Comment: paste the content in `Vagrantfile`

Comment: Im sorry, what content do you mean? i am a big noob on this topic :p

Comment: when you start up a vagrant instance, you need a default or customised `Vagrantfie` file, paste the content here.  If not, you need run `vagrant init` to generate it.

Comment: I have added my vagrantfile to my quetion. I already ran vagrant init and i have two homestead boxes when i run vagrant box list

Answer (score 1):

If this is homestead 2 you need to be using `homestead up` and `homestead suspend` etc.

See `homestead list`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `~/homestead/.Homestead.yaml` file, it contains a configuration for two apps, one with HHVM enabled and one with HHVM disabled(default in homestead).

Homestead will create the database for you in MySQL and PostgreSQL server, when running `homestead up`.

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: jobs.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/jobs/public
    - map: messages.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/messages/web
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - jobs
    - messages

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

You can now run:
    $ `homestead up`

and then:
    $ `homestead ssh`

and then run byobu(for tmux):
    $ `byobu`

and cd into the project:
    $ `cd Projects/jobs`

and run composer:
    $ `composer update`